# Creating a google sign in for a website, but receiving a "Error: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found." error

Tags: javascript, html, google-signin

I am trying to create a google sign in page for my website. This is what I have so far, but whenever the google button is clicked, you just receive a

> Error: invalid_client
>
> The OAuth client was not found.

error.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="288321056572-euu88orq4s5j4acoqmlne9ms3e2hn768.apps.googleusercontent.com
">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Studeo</h1>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What button is clicked?

Comment: Also, please ensure this has occured: `In order to use Google API I must sign in this website [console.developers.google.com] and get a valid Client ID.`

Comment: If you actually have a newline at the end of your `<meta>` `content` attribute, remove it. It will be invalidating your client ID. Ie, it should be `content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"` with the closing `"` immediately following `.com`

Comment: I suspect Phil's comment is the issue.